# pynsq: Giving up RDY count

Tags: python, nsq, pynsq

**WHAT**:

Could someone help me understand what this error message means. `nsqadmin` shows a lot of the messages being requeued / timed out on . Could these logs be the reason?

I am using `pynsq 0.4.2`

**STACKTRACE**

```
2013-07-30 13:34:18,827 DEBUG redistributing RDY state (1 conns > 500 max_in_flight)
2013-07-30 13:34:18,828 DEBUG [ip-10-114-195-89:4150:nsq_msg_handler] rdy: 1 (last message received 268.32s)
2013-07-30 13:34:18,828 INFO [ip-10-114-195-89:4150:nsq_msg_handler] idle connection, giving up RDY count
2013-07-30 13:34:18,828 INFO [ip-10-114-195-89:4150:nsq_msg_handler] redistributing RDY
```

**CODE**

```
    def connect_nsq(self):
        r = nsq.Reader(message_handler=self.nsq_msg_handler, lookupd_http_addresses=["127.0.0.1:4161"], topic="test_topic", channel="test_channel", max_in_flight=500)

        nsq.run()


    # callback
    def nsq_msg_handler(self, message):
        try:
            before_ts = get_utc_now_ts() 
            json_data = json.loads(message.body)

            my_data = json_data["key1"]
            my_data = json_data["key2"]
            my_data = json_data["key3"]

            after_ts = get_utc_now_ts() 
            delta = after_ts - before_ts 
            logger.debug("took %f seconds for json_data _id: %s" % (delta, json_data["_id"])) 
        except Exception as reason:
            print reason, traceback.format_exc()
            return False

       return true
```